# Selecting all versions beginning from a particular version

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

In documentation, suppose I am adding an example for a `C++` topic that came into being `C++11` onwards. Now how do I go about selecting the versions?

Option 1> Select C++11, C++14, and C++17 
Cons: The version following C++17 (as and when it comes) will have to be added manually, or the documentation will become out of date.

Option 2> I should be able to select something like "greater than or equal to C++11"
Pros: No need to add any newer versions when they are released.

I would choose option 2. But how do I do it? I don't find any such option. Should such an option be added?

Comment: It's even worse in Python where we have to select all minor version numbers (2.7.8, 2.7.9, 2.7.10, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checkboxes, versions should be speicified by ranges (max value can be +inf, maybe min value –inf too). Min value inclusive (version when feature was inroduced), max value exclusive (version when feature was dropped). Considering some languages have incompatible branches, multiple ranges must be supported. Like this:

```bash
(2.7.5 <= Version < 3.0) OR (3.2.1 <= Version < +INF)
```